# How to read from block special and character special devices in Linux using bash shell scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to read from /dev/random and /dev/urandom and would like to know what is the best way to read from them and block/character special devices in general using bash shell scripting ?

Comment: I am trying to read them in bash shell constructs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to get blocks of data from the device. E.g. to get 8 bytes from `/dev/urandom`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=8 | ...
```

Then you can use [`od`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/od) to convert the bytes to a human-readable form:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=8 2>/dev/null | od -t x1 -A n
b4 bc 2f 59 dd 55 1b 4a
```

By the way, if you only need random numbers in bash, `$RANDOM` is probably more useful:

```
$ echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
3466 6521 4426 9349
```

Comment: $RANDOM is easier, but not as strong as /dev/urandom

Answer (score 1):

My hint:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=4 | ...
```

or e.g. The tail is heavily dependent on what you want to do with that data

To format as a long integer number:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=4|od -l
```

Comment: I want to generate decimal random numbers.