# Check if a file can actually be opened in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an embedded system where device nodes exist for `/dev/hdaX` and `/dev/sdaX`, and need to check from a bash script which of these correspond to actual devices or not.

The `test` command doesn't help here -- both files actually exist, are "readable" (i.e. have read permissions), and are reported as block devices.

I think the easiest would be to check if the files can actually be opened. Is there a clean way to do this in bash other than e.g. `cat /dev/hdaX` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5797051

Comment: Is the `file` command any use here?

Comment: `file -s` would be great but unfortunately I don't have it in this system.

Comment: @Inian Thank you for the link, that's a good solution for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read` and check exit status:

```
read -n 1 < /dev/hdaX && echo "good" || echo "bad"
```